# Web-to-case email not creating case

Tags: email, case, html, web-to-case, editor

I have followed this outline to create a web to case http://www.crmsalesforcetraining.com/creating-web-to-case-forms-in-salesforce/

and when I go to my cases, nothing has been created. The only difference between this tutorial and what I have is there is no META tag. Could this be causing the issue? the HTML editor will not allow for META tag markups in the html.

What else could it be?

Update:
I also cross checked that the org id was correct

HTML that was generated:

```
<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
<!--  NOTE: Please add the following <META> element to your page <HEAD>.      -->
<!--  If necessary, please modify the charset parameter to specify the        -->
<!--  character set of your HTML page.                                        -->
<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
<!--  NOTE: Please add the following <FORM> element to your page.             -->
<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->

<form action="https://cs99.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToCase?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">
<input type=hidden name="orgid" value="000000000000000">
<input type=hidden name="retURL" value="http://www.google.com">

<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
<!--  NOTE: These fields are optional debugging elements. Please uncomment    -->
<!--  these lines if you wish to test in debug mode.                          -->
<!--  <input type="hidden" name="debug" value=1>                              -->
<!--  <input type="hidden" name="debugEmail" value="notify@omitted.com">    -->
<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->

<label for="name">Contact Name</label><input  id="name" maxlength="80" name="name" size="20" type="text" /><br>
<label for="email">Email</label><input  id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" /><br>
<label for="phone">Phone</label><input  id="phone" maxlength="40" name="phone" size="20" type="text" /><br>
<label for="subject">Subject</label><input  id="subject" maxlength="80" name="subject" size="20" type="text" /><br>
<label for="description">Description</label><textarea name="description"></textarea><br>
<input type="hidden"  id="external" name="external" value="1" /><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML that was generated?

Comment: see updates @JayantDas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, stupid mistake on my part I read the document wrong. I just needed to enable the web to case. Cases are coming in now and emails are being sent out!

Answer (score 0):

Same issue was there for me too, validation rule was blocking this but it won't show any error when you submit the form. Please enable the debugEmail to know the actual issue. It will send an error mail to your inbox.

[image]